# SignalR - keeping updated ConnectionID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm writing a pretty big web system with asp.net MVC, which involves sending data in Real Time to numerous users, based on what they are subscribed to.

My team and I decided to use SignalR for that, and I am in charge of implementing it in the system.

In our case, that a user picks a group to join, and then picks 1 Thing to work on.

For that, I'm saving all the users in a DB. I'll be using the SignalR Groups to handle the first category, and when I need to push a message to a specific user (for the other thing hes picking) I'll just get his ConnectionID from the DB.

Here's the problem - every time the page is refreshed (for instance, when the user picks a group to join) he gets a new connectionID. And now he won't see anything that's pushed to him.

I saw that in the SignalR beta, and on version 2 (I only have 1.1.1 on the computer I'm working on) you can make your own IUserIdProvider (IUserIdPrefixGenerator in the beta), or IUserConnectionIdFactory etc. So I can give him the I'd I want him to have, but I don't seem to have any of those in my version of SignalR.

Comment: i would have a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider it mentions a few suggestions to implemnet what you require

Comment: A connection is not the same thing as a user, a user can have many concurrent connections if he have tabs

Comment: But can the user still receive messages to his first connections?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, but perhaps one of the simplest ways is to associate the new connection id with the user (maybe they still have the other connection open in a different tab).  This can be done using any combination of IP Address, User-Agent, Headers, or location.  Another good candidate for this is either to use sessions, or just a simple identifier cookie (which is more or less what a session would do anyway).

I'll often use GUIDs for this and then create a table in the database when a new identifier cookie is created.  Every time the user "refreshes" or opens a new tab, the cookie can be read in JS and sent with the `hub.connect()`.  Then, you can create an association between the new connection id and the existing identifier cookie.

Comment: Thanks, but since my hub has no idea which user is connected to him at the moment (only connection IDs), I can't associate the connection I'd with the user, except when he picks the group to join.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't you write a cookie the first time a user visits (that will stay with them)?  The point of this is to give you something by which you can identifier the user, no matter which connection ID they have.

Comment: The point is, SignalR uses connection IDs to send messages to clients. Once a client refreshes the page, he has a new connection ID. I have already implemented code which saves a cookie with the user's details, but I couldn't override the default connection ID provider to make him use the original one.

Comment: I see, so if you already have a persistent ID, I wouldn't override the SignalR connection ID.  Instead, I would send your hub messages to every connection ID with that persistent ID.  Almost like a "sub-group" for just that user on all of their connection IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend figuring out a different way to maintain your users' ***persisted*** connections.  Typically, I keep all of my users connection ids stored in a concurrent dictionary to allow for thread-safe access to the collection.  I remove the users from the dictionary whenever a disconnection event occurs and I add them whenever a connection event occurs.

SignalR will manage your users' connections for you.  For you to do it in the database and fall out of sync with SignalR circumvents a lot of the mechanics that make it work correctly in the first place.

```
  private readonly static Lazy<App> _instance = new Lazy<App>(
        () => new App(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AppHub>().Clients));

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    private IHubConnectionContext Clients { get; set; }

    public App(IHubConnectionContext clients)
    {
        Clients = clients;
    }
```

Comment: @Akabutz Sorry, I should have clarified.  User is a custom object that contains whatever identifier you'd like for the user (Id, username from identity context, ect), and a connection id or even list of connection ids.  If you capture that information on the connection of the user, you'll have it perpetuated in memory